# Using Git to communicate relevant changes for pull request vs. showing temporary changes to manager

Tags: git, version-control

I work in a small startup.  I am the only developer working on a big feature which involves changes to 100+ files, and I often need to go back and rewrite many parts of my codebase as requirements change and previous implementations must be redesigned.

When my feature is ready, my pull request will be reviewed by just one other developer.  In order to write clean commit messages, my workflow has been to *not* write any commits at all until the entire feature is ready.  Then, I would group related files into commit messages, and then open a pull request.  I know it may be possible to squash and rewrite Git history, but I think there are many situations where this doesn't work well, and it may be best to just avoid making any commits to have to rewrite later. (Meanwhile, I regularly archive my entire working directory to back up in the cloud, just in case.)

Recently, my manager (who is proficient at reading code and understanding CS concepts, but lacks experience as a developer) asked me to show my progress and save my work with Git.  I explained to him my reasons above for having no commits to show at the moment, and that I disagree with the manager's request.

I want to use Git to communicate relevant changes to other developers, whereas manager just wants to see the temporary codebase changing over time, which can be fulfilled without Git.  I told my manager he can access my cloud backup, but he said he actually wants to read Git commit messages and diffs to see how the temporary codebase is changing over time – the exact things I want to avoid committing to keep commit history clean for PR review.  (I also suggested I could use another version control system alongside Git, so I would push all changes in this other VC for manager, and I get to keep my Git history clean for PR, but this idea seems like madness to me.)

What are technical reasons to use or not use a "No commits at all until it's time to make a PR" strategy? How can I use Git properly to fulfill the requirements of my manager and at the same time keep my current workflow?

Comment: "(Meanwhile, I regularly archive my entire working directory to back up in the cloud, just in case.)" You are literally using a *worse* solution because you don't want to use the one that's built into git. Make a messy development branch with as meaningless commits as you wish "more stuff" is a perfectly acceptable commit message for those. And when you're done squash them all to have a nice result.

Answer (score 0):

The philosophy of Git is to commit as much as you need atomic and working units of code, in order to revert buggy changes when required (not possible if you issue a single commit!).

As corollary, you are able, but not forced, to squash/rewrite the history in order to make it more readable before issue a PR.